# Photography Community Database

Tags: database, photography, gallery

I have been planning a photography community site where;

1. Users can easily register and upload photos (maybe integrate with Facebook and other social media logins).
2. Users can comment/like.
3. The site has a feed (blog-like) with the newest photo uploads at the top
4. Images can be tagged for their theme (e.g. landscape, a street name, a year)
5. Popular tags are displayed prominently
6. An easy to use search feature searches by tag and dynamically displays an album of images that fit that tag.

The problem is while there are plenty of galleries, blogs and social media sites and software out there, I can't find one that does all of it in one. Facebook pages/groups are great but they are too temporary, they can't provide you with a nice database of images going back into the past. A gallery doesn't have the community/social side to it, and a blog might approach what I want but I haven't quite been able to make Wordpress do what I want.

I want the site to become a photographic record of a place, with a search for a street name revealing how it looks now, but also how it looked years ago. I want normal users who might not have photos to contribute to still be able to help by tagging images, or discuss the photo or the history of the place.

Any ideas? Does something like this exist or will I have to code it myself? (which I keep starting and giving up on because I just can't find the time).

Comment: Due to the very specific nature olf your needs I think you will need to find something close to what you want and then modify it to fit your exact purposes.

Comment: something like this: http://www.photosight.ru/ but it's only in Russian ;(